# How can I select items in a gridview while disabling IsHitTestVisible

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a GridView with a small number of items in it.  I want my users to be able to select the items by clicking on them.  However if they click or drag on the GridView background, i.e. on a item, then I want the event to pass through to the control beneath.

If I set MyGridView.IsHitTestVisible = false then I can manipulate items below the grid but then I can't select my grid items.  Setting IsHitTestVisible = true on the ItemTemplate doesn't help.

How can I do this?

Comment: How do you mean "Select", do you mean "Set the GridView's SelectedItem to the clicked Item"? Or do you mean "Set a value 'Selected' on the Control/Item itself"?

Comment: Yes, I mean set the grid views SelectedItem to the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `GridView`'s `SelectedItem` to your ViewModel (you're using Mvvm, right?). Then, on interaction with the Item, set the `SelectedItem` of the ViewModel to the `DataContext` of said item. To do this, make a `Button` in your `ItemTemplate`, then bind a `Command` to your ViewModel with the `CommandParameter` bound to your `DataContext`.

If using Mvvm Light's RelayCommand, it would go something like this:

In your ViewModel:

```
private Item _selectedItem;
public Item SelectedItem
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set { _selectedItem = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
}

public RelayCommand<Item> SetSelectedItemCommand
{
    get;
    private set;
}

private void _setSelectedItem(Item item)
{
    SelectedItem = item;
}

    //Constructor
public ViewModel()
{
    SetSelectedItemCommand = new RelayCommand<Item>(item => _setSelectedItem(item));
}
```

In your ItemTemplate:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyVM.SetSelectedItemCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        <!--Whatever else you want to show in your item-->
</Button>
```

In your GridView:

```
<GridView SelectedItem="{Binding MyVM.SelectedItem, Source="{StaticResource Locator}}"
          ...
</GridView>
```

You'll need to further style the `Button` to remove additional bordering and padding, etc. Not too hard and there should be plenty of other guides on how to do this.

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.  If MyGridView.IsHitTestVisible == false then I can't click on the buttons.  If it is true then I can't manipulate anything behind the grid.

Comment: Ah. Have you tried setting just the ItemsPanel's `IsHitTestVisible` to `false`?